# One repository for more entities?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am programming library collecting some data. It will be able to switch its repositories to change data destination (database/files). I have more entities to store, such as cities, streets etc. My plan is to publish an interface, which will bee needed to implement, to create custom repository for custom data store.

I have seen, each repository takes care of one entity. But in such case, there should be more interfaces - for each repository. Is it OK (in repository design pattern mean) to create single repository accepting all needed entities and publish just one interface? With more interfaces there is possibility to forget to implement some and create inconsistent data api.

Is there better way how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to create a `GeographicRepository` that would contain references to multiple datasources, and accept `featureType` as parameter.

A possible way to use this would be (pseudocode):

```
var rep = new GeoRepository();
var citylist = rep.getEntities(featureType='city');

// or instead:
var citylist = rep.getCities()
```

EDIT: a suggestion based on the central repo vs. fragmented repo would be to have a `RepositoryFaçade` to be an aggregator of individual (and individually testable) repositories:

```
var centralRepo = new GeoRepository();
centralRepo.connectRepository(new GoogleCityRepo());
centralRepo.connectRepository(new YahooVillagesRepo());
centralRepo.connectRepository(new USGSDatabaseRepo('C:\usgs_usa_counties.db'));
```

Of course the way to create/declare "connections" would vary: hardcoded in the constructor, depending on service availabilty, explicit (as shown above), whatever. Also, that would allow for individual testing by writing a harness façade that would call only a single repo.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you want some ideas about a repository of geographic features, you can get some inspiration here (which deals with WEB service, but not necessarily has to be web-based, or http based, or xml based): http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs

Comment: For my need this would be the right way. My repository will remain easy - I just need to save about 10 kinds of entities. But all should be done in a transaction, so this saves me from implementing of such kind of unit of work. Because other answers are useful too, upvoting them. Thank you guys for your advices.

Answer (score 2):

Each repository can return different entities. But if you group everything together in one interface, it would be really hard for other developers to read and maintain. In my development project, we try to make sure the each repository return related entities.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I usually go for hybrid in the sense that, I have a base repository and extending repositories which would need custom implementation.

ie:

```
public class BaseRepo<T> : IRepo<T> where T: TEntity
{
  // common functionality for all repos
  // such as find, add, remove etc.
}
```

However, most of the time you will need more than CRUD, especially for selects.

It is a terrible idea to pass around expression trees which kills you testability and maintainability.

Moreover, You wont be able to use Dependency Injection if you have a single repo, which you is certainly doable. But highly discouraged.

You need to separate the responsibilities of repositories. Follow SOLID principles. and create a good API.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:** Yes, you can use a single repository for all operations.

**Long Answer:** When i first started using repositories, i thought the only approach was to use a repository for each entity then i found this excellent article ["Query Objects with the Repository Pattern"](http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2008/08/02/query-objects-with-the-repository-pattern/) where the author discussed whether to use a single repository per aggregate root or a repository for each entity, or just a single repository for the whole thing. He concluded with a very tempting opinion to use a single repository for everything with the combination of query object pattern for querying the data source, i really liked the end result and you might.

Comment: I totally disagree with Author, with you and everyone else on that matter. You can also find many authors who would disagree as well. First of all, your testability will suck, because you will need more generic functionality for a given repo. Also, it is not a good idea to pass around expression threes and IQueryable<T>. follow SOLID principles!

Comment: @DarthVader i don't want to start a discussion here in the comments, but i would like to point out that i am still using an interface per entity. With that out of the way, i would like to say that the way the author implemented his idea is pretty testable and doesn't involve passing expression trees around and i feel that it is still better than someone claiming he is doing repository per entity when he is actually deriving his repositories from a common base class including all kinds of operations violating all sorts or principles.

Comment: i m not starting a discussion but since when inheritance is violating all sorts of principles. how about liskov subs. principle?

Comment: @DarthVader this is turning into a discussion alright. I wasn't talking about inheritance but rather about the base class with all sorts of operations that they pretend it is generic for all repositories returning IQueryable<T> and accepting expression trees. One last thing, god knows i love polymorphism and the liskov sub principle is one of my favorites.

Comment: I would like to point some aspects that might matter: 1) Design patterns are intended to be used as general principles to be adapted to each particular need; 2) using one repository that's actually a "mashup" of different (types of) data sources is a good example of Façade pattern and Adapter pattern (as I understand them) besides being a Repository pattern. 3) Even the most notable auhors (Martin Fowler comes to mind) aren't so assertive about one approach being "wrong" and other being "right". Every sensible approach would have benefits and shortcomings. IMHO.